# How to change usb number?

Tags: android, usb, tty, usb-drive

I'm going to let my GPS and 4G module worked.

My 4G module will using ttyACM0~5.

My GPS is using ttyACMX.

Here is the problem, 4G module need to be using on ttyACM0~5.

But if GPS power on first then it will take ttyACM0 and will cause my 4G module can't worked.

So I'm trying to let GPS tied on ttyACM6 when booting but I don't know how to do it.

Which driver should I modify or any other methods can get this worked?

Answer (score 0):

if you have i.e. *vendor id* and *product id*  of your GPS and 4G device you can *assign static device nodes* in linux using `udev` rules

this is described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name and http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/01/statically-assign-dev-nodes-to-hardware-devices-in-linux/

the name of the static device node can be chosen in the `SYMLINK+="..."` field

you can get vendor id and product id of your devices with `lsusb` or `lsusb -v` when your devices are plugged in ...

Comment: sorry, I had not announce that I'm using Android 7.1.

In my system I have no /etc/udev/rule.d/10-local.rules file to add the Action and AYMLINK conmmand.

Comment: added android tag to question, currently do not know how to handle this in android ...